# Elasticsearch object mapping for tried to parse field [null] as object, but found a concrete value

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

How can I change mapping or my input to resolve these error, using elasticsearch on AWS,

Mapping:

```json
    {
        "index_patterns": ["*-students-log"],
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "Data": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "PASSED": {
                            "type": "object"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "insertion_timestamp": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "epoch_second"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My data :

```sh
    curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://******.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/index_name/_doc/1 -d '{"Data": {"PASSED": ["Vivek"]},"insertion_timestamp": 1591962493}'
```

Error I got :

```json
    {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"object mapping for [Data.PASSED] tried to parse field [null] as object, but found a concrete value"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"object mapping for [Data.PASSED] tried to parse field [null] as object, but found a concrete value"},"status":400}
```

What is the missing or wrong piece in the above data? Is there any other datatype I should use for array of string?
Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

JSON ***arrays*** are **not** considered JSON ***objects*** when ingested into Elasticsearch.

The docs state the following regarding [arrays](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html):

> There is no dedicated array datatype. Any field can contain zero or
> more values by default, however, all values in the array must be of
> the same datatype.

So, instead of declaring the whole array as an `object`, speficy the array entries' data type (`text`) directly:

```json
PUT abc-students-log
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "Data": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "PASSED": {
            "type": "text"   
          }
        }
      },
      "insertion_timestamp": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "epoch_second"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```json
POST abc-students-log/_doc
{
  "Data": {
    "PASSED": [
      "Vivek"
    ]
  },
  "insertion_timestamp": 1591962493
}
```