# Elasticsearch update nested field with painless script in ElasticSearch API vs java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless, elasticsearch-java-api, elasticsearch-scripting

Could someone explain what's wrong with ES java api?
I'm making query to update by script with ES api and it works perfectly (below)

```
POST user/ut/520411_5752/_update
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.cars.add(params.car)",
    "params": {
      "car": {
        "pub_id":155,
        "name":"qwerty"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and java

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("car", GSON.toJson(car));

Script inline = new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless",
"ctx._source.cars.add(params.car)", 
params);
    
UpdateRequest request = new UpdateRequest(USER, UT, id).script(inline).retryOnConflict(1);
UpdateResponse update = elasticClient.update(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

As you may guess java is failing with exception

```
ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=object mapping for [cars] tried to parse field [null] as object, but found a concrete value]]
```

Tried different options, with empty *car* field, with filled *car* field, everytime getting an exception above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like i surrender with RestHighLevelClient.
But i remember that i have LowLevelClient and rewrite my update using it and it's working fine.
Since i don't need to check the response, i don't need to parse it too.

Answer (score 1):

Your java code LGTM and the problem comes from a "stale" version of your mapping that wouldn't be compatible with what your script would end up adjusting. Check [my other answer from a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62358568/8160318) to gain more insight into this cryptic-sounding error.

Simply put, make sure your mapping looks something like this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "cars": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "pub_id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

that is, `cars` as an object and its contents clearly defined too. After that your script should work just fine.

BTW just to be perfectly safe, I'd add two more checks before I called `.add`:

```
if (ctx._source.cars != null && ctx._source.cars instanceof ArrayList) { ctx._source.cars.add(params.car) }
```

Comment: Thank you Joe, but i need to keep this field nested.

Comment: Oh I see, well then replace `"type": "object"` with `"type": "nested"`!

Comment: So, checked the mapping, it's fine. I don't know what's wrong with the HighLevel Rest client. But I tried with Low level client and it's working right exactly like the query from Kibana.

Comment: Anyway thank you again Joe, you helped a lot.

Comment: All good -- you're welcome. I tend to stick w/ low-level queries myself.